# Count occurrence of string in XPath attribute

Tags: xml, string, xpath

Is it possible to select the nodes that has say "n" number of reoccurrences of a string / character sequence in the value of the attribute of nodes?

For example:

```
<IOCFG xmlns="http://www.br-automation.com/AR/IO" Version="2.0">
    <Module ID="$root.IO" Hardware="X20CP1484">
    </Module>
    <Module ID="$rot.IO" Hardware="X20CP1484">
    </Module>
    <Module ID="$rt.IO" Hardware="X20CP1484">
    </Module>
    **<Module ID="IF3.IF1.ST9" Hardware="Hello"/>**
    <Module ID="IF3.IF2.IF3.ST9" Hardware="Bye"/>
    **<Module ID="IF3.IF2.ST1" Hardware="hai"/>**
</IOCFG>
```

From the above file I could only select the nodes with ID (attribute) which has 'IF' string occurring twice.

Comment: Is the format of ID always the same? A sequence of two letters followed by a number and a dot? If it is, you could use XPath 2.0 function `matches`, which matches a string to a regular expression... As long as using XPath 2.0 is an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to count the matches using XPath, but you can cheat by using the substring-after function:

```
//*[contains(substring-after(@id, "IF"), "IF")]
```

This  looks for all elements that have an ID attribute that contain the string "IF" after the string "IF" (which is equivalent to "IF" two times). It's not as readable as I would like, but it works. I tested it out using this interactive xpath tester: http://ponderer.org/download/xpath/

Edit: As the other Tom pointed out, this will match IDs that have two or more "IF"s. To make it only match IDs that have exactly two "IF"s, you would need

```
//*[contains(substring-after(@id, "IF"), "IF") and not(contains(substring-after(substring-after(@id, "IF"), "IF"), "IF"))]
```

But that looks pretty ugly to me (it's matching IDs that have 2 or more "IF"s but not IDs that have 3 or more "IF"s).

Comment: This would also match strings, in which "IF" occurs more than twice.

Answer (score 7):

If you're in XPath 2.0, then `count(tokenize(., 'IF'))=3` will test whether IF appears twice.

Comment: since I use Xpath 1.0 and the parser is pugi, I couldn't use this solution -but **substring-after** works quite well for me. Thank you Mr.Kay and Mr.Novatchev

Answer (score 3):

**Use this XPath expression**:

```
/*/*
   [translate(@ID, translate(@ID, 'IF', ''), '')='IFIF']
```

**XSLT-based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "/*/*
      [translate(@ID, translate(@ID, 'IF', ''), '')='IFIF']

     "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<IOCFG xmlns="http://www.br-automation.com/AR/IO" Version="2.0">
<Module ID="$root.IO" Hardware="X20CP1484">
</Module>
<Module ID="$rot.IO" Hardware="X20CP1484">
</Module>
<Module ID="$rt.IO" Hardware="X20CP1484">
</Module>
**<Module ID="IF3.IF1.ST9" Hardware="Hello"/>**
<Module ID="IF3.IF2.IF3.ST9" Hardware="Bye"/>
**<Module ID="IF3.IF2.ST1" Hardware="hai"/>**
</IOCFG>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the selected elements are copied to the output:**

```
<Module xmlns="http://www.br-automation.com/AR/IO" ID="IF3.IF1.ST9" Hardware="Hello"/>
<Module xmlns="http://www.br-automation.com/AR/IO" ID="IF3.IF2.ST1" Hardware="hai"/>
```

**Do note**:

This is a *rough* solution that assumes the values of the `ID` attribute have certain properties (as in the provided XML). The same XPath expression maynot produce correct results if this assumption is broken.

One precise XPath 1.0 expression that selects only such elements whose `ID` attribute contains the string `"IF"` exactly twice is:

```
  /*/*
  [contains(@ID, 'IF')
  and contains(substring-after(@ID, 'IF'), 'IF')
  and not(contains(
              substring-after(substring-after(@ID, 'IF'),'IF'),
              'IF')
          )
  ]
```